# data recovery issue using foremost tool

Tags: data-recovery, storage, data

i am trying to recover data using **foremost** data recovery tool in my ubuntu os

foremost recovers most known file formats by default like **png, jpg, pdf** and others, but i mainly need to recover files with **.txt** format, so

i should edit the foremost **config** file and enable **txt** format for tool support like the follwoing:

[image: txt support in foremost]

- **After recovery got finished**, all the txt files were returned with **PGP signature** and those files were not readable.
- **the problem is:** foremost always returns the txt files with **GPG signature** and that's because the **header** marked above which in my opinion instructs foremost to return
  all **txt files starts with gpg signature**
- **I want to** change this header to return files with **normal text format** that we always work with
- So, what is the default **header** should i change to in order to return normal format text files?

Comment: hope so, but unfortuately  there is no other extentions explicitly defined except for this one with PGP header

Comment: Sorry can't help further